# Unable to Merge Win7 Partition with Unallocated Space Released from Xubuntu

Tags: windows, partitioning, gparted, resize

Please see the current partitions in Gparted below [edit - I wasn't allowed to post an image, I just posted the output of fdisk -l], I have moved & resized my Xubuntu partition in order to allocate more space to Win7. However I am unable to resize Win7 into it.

I presume it has something to do with sda3 being marked as"extended" and cordend off. I've googled around to know avail.

Can you help?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2baa4004

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    58969747    29381450    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        58970110   312580095   126804993    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       100741120   310597631   104928256   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       310599680   312580095      990208   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extended partition starts just after the Win 7 partition.

You need to reduce the size of the extended partition before you'll be able to enlarge the Win 7 partition.

So using a live CD/DVD/USB open Gparted, resize the /dev/sda3 partition first. Then it should be possible to enlarge /dev/sda2.